# JS function is not getting called

Tags: javascript

Here is my JSP code:

```
       <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
           pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
       <html>
       <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
       <title>Order a PIZZA</title>

       </head>
       <body>
       <b>SUBIR'S JUST IN PIZZA</b><br>
       <i>All PIZZAs in just 30 minutes</i>
       <div align="left">
       Pizza=150/-<br>
       Garlic Bread=60/-<br>
       Soft drink=45/-<br>
       Extra Cheese=45/-<br>
       Tax=12.25%
       </div>
        <div align="right">
            Name:
            <input type="text"><br>
            Number of Pizza:
            <input type="text" id="pizza" onchange="pizza_calculate()"><br>
            Number of Garlic breads:
            <input type="text"><br>
            Number of Soft drinks::
            <input type="text"><br>
            Number of Extra cheese:
            <input type="text"><br>
            Total:
            <input type="text" id="total"><br>
            Tax:
            <input type="text"><br>
            <input type="button" value="reload">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="evaluate.js"></script>
        </div>
       </body>
       </html>
```

My evaluate.JS javascript is the following:

```
var price=0;
var tax=0;
var pizza=150;
var garlicBread=60;
var softdrink=45;
var extraCheese=45;
var pizza_total=0;
var softdrink_total=0;
function pizza_calculate()
{
var test=document.getElementById("pizza");
console.log(test);
pizza_total=document.getElementById("pizza")*pizza;
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML =pizza_total;
};
```

From Firebug I understand that my JS function is not getting executed. What might possibly be the reason for this error, please suggest.

Comment: Try using `pizza_calculate = function() { ...your function...}`

Comment: `pizza_total=document.getElementById("pizza")*pizza;` That won't work.

Comment: What is `*pizza` supposed to do?  What is `pizza`?  Also, `document.getElementById("pizza")` returns the element, not its value.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your doctype should be `<!doctype html>`. The one you have is for HTML4, and the one in this comment is for HTML5.

Comment: @Jonathan, What should I use for multiplication then?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, Pizza is a variable here consisting value of each pizza; it is supposed to get multiplied with number of pizzas.

Comment: "From Firebug I understand that my JS function is not getting executed." what does that mean? What happens? Do you have error messages? If you do, maybe that would be helpful to include in your question?

Comment: @Havvy, thanks for bringing it to notice. Will do necessary changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
pizza_total=document.getElementById("pizza")*pizza;
```

should be:

```
var pizza_total = parseInt( document.getElementById("pizza").value, 10) * pizza;
```

Or, since you already have the element as a `test` variable, simply:

```
var pizza_total = parseInt(test.value, 10) * pizza;
```

---

UPDATE

```js
var price = 0;
var tax = 0;
var pizza = 150;
var garlicBread = 60;
var softdrink = 45;
var extraCheese = 45;
var pizza_total = 0;
var softdrink_total = 0;

function pizza_calculate() {
  var test = document.getElementById("pizza");
  var pizza_total = parseInt(test.value, 10) * pizza;
  document.getElementById("total").value = pizza_total;
};
```

```html
<div align="right">
  Name:
  <input type="text">
  <br>Number of Pizza:
  <input type="text" id="pizza" onchange="pizza_calculate()">
  <br>Number of Garlic breads:
  <input type="text">
  <br>Number of Soft drinks::
  <input type="text">
  <br>Number of Extra cheese:
  <input type="text">
  <br>Total:
  <input type="text" id="total">
  <br>Tax:
  <input type="text">
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="reload">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</div>
```

Note, if you wish instant updates, you can use `onkeyup` instead of `onchange`.

Comment: You should fetch values from an `input` tag with `.value`, not with `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Just to help the guy who asked the question: `parseInt(x,10);` makes sure the value you send is an integer compared on base 10. More info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Good job Shomz!

Comment: Yes, thank you for the addition, @JeffNoel! `150 * test.value` would probably work, but `parseInt` is always better.

Comment: My intenetion was to autopopulate the total value of pizzas ordered in the `total` textbox. However still after doing the modifications it is not getting populated. Why is that?Any idea?

Comment: See the live example, you had one more error: `document.getElementById("total").value = pizza_total;` note we're again using `value` here, not `innerHTML`.

Comment: @Shomz on a sidenote to the deleted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/338053/2407212 (I'll delete when read)

Comment: @Jonathan, no, leave it, it will be useful to people. I know about it already, I've already upvoted (who knows when) almost everything there. :)

Answer (score 4):

You only grab the DOMElement with the ID Pizza, not its value. Try adding `.value` to get the element's value. Like so:

```
pizza_total= document.getElementById("pizza").value * pizza;
```

Comment: The `pizza` is in scope.  It's in the `var`s above the function.

Comment: My bad, I'll fix that. That was my first assumption after it returned `NaN`. Then I realized he wasn't getting the value. Consider it's always fixed!

Comment: upvoted for explaining `pareseInt(x,10)` in the comment of the above answer

Comment: Hmm, now I see you answered this correctly two minutes before I did. Not sure why I didn't see it when I was writing an answer. Yours should be accepted (even without the parseInt). At least I gave you an upvote.

Comment: @Shomz As long as the question is answered I'm quite happy with the result.

Answer (score 3):

Other people have pointed out a number of problems with your script, but the reason your script isn't running is because you have this:

```
 <input type="text" id="pizza" onchange="pizza_calculate()"><br>
```

parsed before the script is loaded at the end of your html.

`pizza_calculate` isn't defined.

Either move your script to top, or better, don't inline your event handlers and instead use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead.

```
function pizza_calculate()
{
    /* body of pizza_calculate */
}
var pizzaInput = document.getElementById("pizza");
pizzaInput.addEventListener("change", pizza_calculate, false);
```